# Binary not loaded automatically to target by Keil MDK v5

Tags: stm32, keil

I've been using Keil MDK (currently v5.31) for a long time on different products and boards.

Right now, I've ported a project of mine from a Nucleo/STM32H743 to a EVAL2/STM32H753.

Usually when I click on "Start/Stop debug session" button it starts by loading the binary code to Flash (i checked that option "load application at startup" is selected, and that a programming algorithm is provided in Debug>Flash Download).

But on this new setup, the binary loading is not done. However I can still load it by cliking on the "Load" button of Keil.

There is an error message:

```
File       : C:\Keil_v5\Arm\Packs\Keil\STM32H7xx_DFP\2.3.0\Keil.STM32H7xx_DFP.pdsc 

Sequence   : DebugDeviceUnlock 

Context    : Item #0: <block>::Line 8 

Expression : "v5\Arm\Packs\Keil\STM32H7xx_DFP\2.3.0\Keil.STM32H7xx_DFP.pdsc" 

E310       : Debug access failed - cannot read address 0xE00E1004 (accsize '4', AP '0x00000002')
```

The pack (.pdsc file) exists and seems to be the correct one.

Any idea ?